# Maximum number of divs in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that produces a schedule for a project timeline. The timeline is split into days and each day is split into am and pm.

One of the projects in there last for 517 days meaning that the container div will have 1034 inner days (Each representing a slot in a day). In IE8 as soon as we exceed 1000 divs the html simply doesn't show (works fine in chrome and firefox). Does anyone know if there is any kind limit in IE8

The divs are displayed as "display:table-cell" if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation it turned out that IE didn't like more than 1000 nested elements in one element, we ended up having containers that contained upto 1000 elements